# Commercial Availability of Bare Metal Automation Controllers

Tags: microcontroller, embedded, plc, rtos

When I think of commercial automation controllers, I typically see 2 levels of system complexity.

First, at a lower level, PLC's programmable with ladder logic, structured text or another 61131-3 language.

Then, at a higher level, RTOS controller systems.

However, looking at the major commercial vendors (Omron, Mitsubishi, etc.), there appears to be a dearth of intermediate bare metal MCU automation controllers that allow full embedded programming in C or a comparable language but do not have a full OS. Such a device would achieve real-time control through a real-time clock and interrupts.

I can certainly conceive of industrial systems that require more complexity than what structured text allows, but not the full complexity of an operating system.

While this wouldn't be much more than an industrial i/o-ready Arduino or AtmelXMega pre-assembled with accessories, why don't major commercial vendors develop this line of products?

Comment: My guess (not familiar with PLCs much) is that there's no reason not to get the higher level ones instead.

Comment: This market is already dominated by major Japanese and German suppliers with many others , US, Chinese etc

Comment: From my experience, there are times when a less skill person needs to trouble shoot something. Sometimes they have familiarity with old relay logic, ladder logic is similar. Troubleshooting something in C would be a lot more difficult.

Comment: @Dragonsheep  What would the product actually look like?  Would it be an unprogrammed PLC (in an industrial PLC enclosure) with JTAG coming out, published schematic, board support package?

Comment: Ultimately market forces drive what major manufacturers do.

Comment: @Nick Alexeev. Good question. I imagine something between what you've described and something a bit more developed, such that the programmer has the choice of interacting with the various off-chip on-board peripherals (serial, ethernet, analog and digital i/o) through libraries rather than rewriting the basic firmware himself/ herself.

Comment: The market would be small, I suspect.  Relatively few people would embark on the task of programming a bare metal board in C.  That's why large automation suppliers don't sell bare metal PLCs without interpreter or OS.  Groups who would take a trouble of programming a bare metal board in C often can design their own controller.  [I'm saying this, because I have designed hardware for a situation like that.]

Comment: Do you know [PC/104](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PC/104)

Answer (score 1):

I think there are many factors behind it.

Reliability and easy maintenance are very important for the automation industry.  At the same time, factory lines are low volume products, but with lots of capital behind them, so they aren't really cost-sensitive.

But also the harsh reality is that when it comes to technology, the automation industry is far behind other industries. I work with one foot in automation and the other in automotive, so I can easily compare those two - automation is lagging behind by 20 years or so. PLC:s is an old technology and the main reason for using them is probably conservatism.

PLC:s were once much easier to program than microcontrollers. But nowadays we have a standardized C language, awesome free compilers, the ARM market explosion, standardized single-wire debuggers, pre-made code and drivers, the Internet where you can find information and get help quickly etc etc. To make a microcontroller application is much easier today than it was in the 1980s/90s.

And once the development part is over, a custom PCB with a microcontroller costs somewhere around $10-$30, while a PLC costs somewhere around $2000. Eventually even the automation industry will realize this and it will be the death of PLC:s.

As for Arduino specifically, it is of course unsuitable for professional applications, being a hobbyist platform. Using it for industrial applications is nothing but quackery.

Comment: Precisely, you can't not use a higher level language when the intent is to still sell compatible hardware 25 years later. Automotive is much more purpose built.

Answer (score 0):

I've been wanting this for some time myself. One device that meets your criteria is the [Controllino](https://controllino.biz/). I've never tried it myself.

What I've done in the past is used an *actual* arduino instead of the PLC. That's only really suitable for light duty applications, but it's worked great for me.

My co-workers have done this as well to control things like incubators and other non-dangerous equipment. It can save you a lot of time and money if you've got some baseline EE skills.